# How to use a TabLayout with Toolbar inside CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-design-library

I am looking at the [chrisbanes/cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) and I am trying to put TabLayout with a Toolbar inside a CollapsingToolbarLayout, and here is my code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/primary_dark"
            android:minHeight="150dip"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="60dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="110dip"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This puts on something like this when the CollapsingToolbar is opened which is exactly what I am looking for:

[image]

But when I collapse it (by pulling the image up) I get something like this

[image]

And this is due to the reason I've set the Toolbar to have a height of 110dip if I leave the default settings the Tabs and the toolbar title overlap. So I am looking for the right way to do that so that the title of the Toolbar gets it's right place on the appbar and the tablayout is under it. Is there a way this can be achieved ?

Comment: I am not sure since I have just started playing around with the design library myself, but shouldn't there be a `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` on the `TabLayout`?

Comment: @XaverKapeller yeah I've already tried that and it was the logical place to start but that's not it, maybe they haven't yet implemented the pin/parallax feature fully yet :/

Comment: What I would also try is to put the `TabLayout` just inside the `AppBarLayout` and not in the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's the way I managed to do this, I don't think that's the best solution though if anyone finds a better way please feel free to post the answer.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="206dip"
            android:background="@color/primary_dark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="20dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            android:gravity="bottom"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: This works, but the content doesn't seem to want to scroll back once it is hidden.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and the bug JMRboosties mentioned has been fixed in 22.2.1. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178656

Comment: how make TabLayout above CardViews when 
behavior_overlapTop="32dp" is specified for viewpager?

Comment: How do you set the imageview? I am unable to set a single image as background both to the toolbar and the tab? Any hints?

Comment: I think, this is better and working solution: http://blog.grafixartist.com/parallax-scrolling-tabs-design-support-library/

Comment: Obviously, it's not the best solution. OP, and I, want tab's to be over the picture. @Tomas your solution is also incomplete. In it, the title is not moving.

Comment: Tomas your post saved my life! Thank you!
@Marius Kaunietis to have a moving title, you just to set the title to your CollapsingToolbarLayout instead of your Toolbar.

Answer (score 24):

After 2 whole days of trying to find a pure Android solution here is my solution.

**Target: Tabs under the Toolbar with image background behind both views**

**(TL;DR: See XML attached)**

The behavior I want to achieve is to have the *CollapsingToolbarLayout* and the TabLayout on top of an image and when the "header" is scrolled up (out of the screen) then to show the *ActionBar* (toolbar) with the *TabLayout* under it.

**The Problem:**

Since the *CollapsingToolbarLayout* will hide all children views when collapsed except the *Toolbar* view then the *TabLayout* has to be placed outside the *CollapsingToolbarLayout* but inside the *AppBarLayout* so that it is "docked" at the top of the screen and under the *Toolbar*. The issue now is that the *ImageView* placed inside the *CollapsingToolbarLayout* will not be under the *TabLayout* but above it vertically.

**The Solution:**

To solve this issue we need to make the ImageView taller so that if we were to place the *TabLayout* inside the *CollapsingToolbarLayout* it will cover it. But because we placed the *TabLayout* outside the *CollapsingToolbarLayout*  we need to make sure that the *ImageView* is drawn even if its parent view (*CollapsingToolbarLayout*) is shorter. **clipChildren="false"** TO THE RESCUE! clipChildren tells a *ViewGroup* to DO NOT clip its children view if they are bigger than it's size, so essentially now we can make the *ImageView* taller and it will still be drawn under the *TabLayout*. This way we can have both the *CollapsingToolbarLayout* and the *TabLayout* above a nice image!

**My Layout xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipChildren="false" /////IMPORTANT!!!!!!
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:clipChildren="false"  /////IMPORTANT!!!!!!
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/poster"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

Comment: @PhoenixWang please feel free to provide a solution that works with scrimContent

Comment: Great answer but to solve the problem of the contentScrim what I did is used a semi-transparent color <color name="black_overlay_dark">#88000000</color> as the app:tabBackground="@color/black_overlay_dark" and app:contentScrim="@color/black_overlay_dark" Looks cool yeah!!

Answer (score 14):

It turns out that since the AppBarLayout extends LinearLayout, you can have two CollapsingToolBarLayouts (extends FrameLayout) in it. What I did was have the first CollapsingToolBarLayout house the contents I wanted to disappear, and gave it the AppBarLayout flag:

app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"

For the second CollapsingToolbarLayout that actually had the tabs, I set it's scroll flags to:

app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

The final XML looks like this and it gives me what I want.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="@dimen/quadruple_margin"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/header_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:background="@color/black_40">

                <!-- YOUR CONTENT HERE -->

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/action_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
                app:contentInsetLeft="@dimen/triple_margin"
                app:contentInsetStart="@dimen/triple_margin"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
                app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/half_margin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
                app:tabBackground="@color/transparent"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/grey_400" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: That's also a nice idea :)

Comment: This is working fine.but not getting app:tabBackground="@color/transparent" in second CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: @AthiraSanthosh @color/transparent is a color you have to define in your res/values/colors.xml like this:

    <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>

Comment: I have used this.but i am getting first CollapsingToolbarLayout background color in second CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: Looks rotten. Is this the best Android can do. Doubt it.

Answer (score 7):

I've created this [sample](https://github.com/vitovalov/TabbedCoordinatorLayout) project where I use TabLayout inside of CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tested on API 14-23. Works without any problems.

Answer (score 6):

I found a simple solution to make it works with transparent `TabLayout` background:

- use `expandedTitleMarginBottom` in `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to avoid expanded title overlapping `TabLayout`
- set `layout_height` to `TabLayout` as constant value
- add `layout_marginBottom` to `Toolbar` with same value as `TabLayout` `layout_height`

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="70dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <YourMagicViewWithBackgroundImageTextAndOtherStuff
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: This is the most straight forward and simple solution. It works with scrimContent and should be the accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: Working like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

collapsing toolbar with tabs using new material design support library example with source code

I used official collapsing toolbar feature of new material design support library.

here collapsed view height is 256dp and tabs height is 56dp

i made following path,i cut image into two parts one for collapsed view and one for tabs.

i cutted images according to [dp to pixel](http://androidpixels.net/) sizes with high resolution drawable xxxhdpi and put into drawable folder so it will adjustable to all screen sizes

i have 2000x1246 image

top image 256dp= 2000x1024 pixel

bottom tab image 56dp= 2000x224 pixel

Here is the complete example with [source code](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/collapsing-toolbar-with-tabs-android-example/)

[image]

Comment: Nice idea, though I suppose, no parallax.

Answer (score 2):

**Use This Code XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/PrimaryColor"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/background_material"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleMarginTop="15dp"/>



        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabsInLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpagerDetail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Java code**

```
  collapsingToolbarLayout =    (CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.collapse_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(false);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(cheeseName);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled is working on 23 sdk version or above

Answer (score 1):

Here is my idea of doing this.

I place tab layout outside the AppBar and wrap it with vertical Linear Layout and set the position like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabDetail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you don't wrap TabLayout with another twice height Layout. When you set layout_anchor to AppBar, only half of TabLayout will be in AppBar.

Here is my whole XML file.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpagerDetail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="54dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabDetail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not sure if these set of dp value will fit your screen size but it do with mine. If anyone has better answer please share.

Sorry if i make a mistake on my code or my english.Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and my solution was ridiculously simple. All I had to do was setting the toolbar as the support actionbar (I am using a `Theme.NoActionBar` style base)

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below implements the action Expand / Collapse toolbar.

Basically we will have a
`CoordinatorLayout` (FrameLayout)
`AppBarLayout` (vertical LinearLayout Which implements many of the features of stuff designs),
`CollapsingToolbarLayout` (is a wrapper for Toolbar)
ImageView and Toolbar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/logo"
            android:minHeight="300dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            android:gravity="bottom"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fr_container_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Observation
- FrameLayout is necessary app: layout_behavior = "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
-TOOLBAR Not need backgroud, insert the color in the attribute app:contentScrim = "?Attr/ColorPrimary" from our CollapsingToolbarLayout
```

In your class

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
mCollapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("YourTitle");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

I placed the TabLayout outside the AppBarLayout and wrapped the ViewPager and TabLayout together inside a LinearLayout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="@color/profile_header_bg_color"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:background="@color/profile_header_bg_color">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="60dp"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:background="@color/profile_header_bg_color"
            android:id="@+id/user_details"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:background="@color/profile_header_bg_color"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" >

        <include layout="@layout/YOUR-CONTENT-LAYOUT" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
        android:background="@color/primary_color" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ui.screen.ProfileView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/profile_viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_appbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:elevation="2dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
                app:elevation="2dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/profile_user_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="192dp"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:clipChildren="false"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="24dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
                    android:paddingRight="24dp"
                    android:paddingTop="64dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clipChildren="false"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:layout_width="96dp"
                            android:layout_height="96dp"
                            android:clipChildren="false">

                            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                                android:id="@+id/profile_user_photo"
                                android:layout_width="86dp"
                                android:layout_height="86dp"
                                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                                app:border_width="1dp"
                                app:border_color="@color/white" />

                            <View
                                android:id="@+id/profile_user_medal"
                                android:layout_width="24dp"
                                android:layout_height="24dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/medal"
                                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="top|right" />

                        </FrameLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/profile_user_details"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/profile_user_name"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="KateÅ™ina BÃ­la"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="24sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/profile_user_completed_activities"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Dokoncene 4 z 5"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="16sp" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/profile_user_progress_text"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:textSize="20sp"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    android:text="50%" />

                                <com.rey.material.widget.ProgressView
                                    android:id="@+id/profile_user_progress_bar"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="6dp"
                                    android:visibility="visible"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                                    app:pv_progressMode="determinate"
                                    app:pv_circular="false"
                                    app:pv_autostart="true"
                                    app:lpd_strokeSize="3dp"
                                    app:lpd_strokeColor="@color/red"
                                    app:lpd_strokeSecondaryColor="@color/white"
                                    app:lpd_maxLineWidth="62dp"
                                    app:lpd_minLineWidth="31dp"
                                    app:pv_progressStyle="@style/ProfileTotalProgressBar"
                                    app:pv_progress="0.5" />


                            </LinearLayout>


                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                app:elevation="2dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/profile_tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/white_87"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextAppearance"
                    app:elevation="2dp" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</ui.screen.ProfileView>
```

This works for me but only on devices with api 19+

Answer (score 0):

As someone pointed out before, it looks like this is because (from the docs):

> The navigation button is vertically aligned within the Toolbar's
>   minimum height, if set.

Therefore, based on the initial layout you can do something like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/primary_dark"
            android:minHeight="150dip"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="60dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

             <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="110dip"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                app:titleMarginTop="13dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Where app:titleMarginTop is the spacing needed to get the Toolbar size minus TabLayout size minus the text size and it should align nicely.

Answer (score 0):

All above codes are collapsing only "CollapsingtoolbarLayout" components. That means if we scroll the page of "ViewPager" content, it is not working.

I replace the "ViewPager" by "FrameLayout" now it is working, what we expecting.

I am expecting like, if scroll the page of Viewpager then "CollapsingToolbarLayout" should be listen. for this I used the "NestedScrollView". But problem is "ViewPager" not working in "NestedScrollView".

So finally I achieved with FrameLayout.

> But problem is "tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new
>   TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {"  is depricated

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />-->

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:src="@drawable/srl_mallikaarjuna_lrg"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"

                />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                >
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:text="Calendar"/>
                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
              >

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fefefe"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

  <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/frame_container">

  </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Creating The Tablayout with out ViewPager : http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/easy-way-to-create-tab-layout-in-android-without-viewpager

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar> set margin bottom to 48dp and layout_height to ?attr/actionBarSize

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark"
        android:minHeight="150dip"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="60dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get this working by placing the `TabLayout` inside a second `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with the scroll flag set to enter Always Collapsed.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/event_guide_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/event_guide_collapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="80dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/event_guide_banner_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/darkened_placeholder"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/event_guide_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/event_guide_tabbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/BaseTheme"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/event_guide_swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_gray"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.meetball.activity.EventGuideActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/event_guide_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to put the `Toolbar` inside the `CollapsingToolbar` with `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` and the `TabLayout` outside with `app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"`