# How to display tabLayout over the viewPager bottom on scrolling in android?

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am a newbie to android material design. I am trying to do the following:
I am placing a `ToolBar` at the top, followed by a `ViewPager` and a `TabLayout` at the bottom of my layout. When I scroll the `ViewPager` to the `toolbar` hides but the `TabLayout` does not appear over the ViewPager. The TabLayout pushes the ViewPager up and is displayed below the ViewPager. Can anyone help me to display the TabLayout at the top of the ViewPager. My layout is as below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"

        android:background="@color/turquoise"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imv_drop_down"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/test" />

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imv_drop_down"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Text"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"

                android:textSize="@dimen/common_btn_text" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imv_search"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/test" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imv_notify"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imv_search"
                android:src="@drawable/test" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color"

    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: For starters, take the ViewPager out of the AppBarLayout

Comment: use collapsing layout with toolbar.....check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680824/how-to-use-a-tablayout-with-toolbar-inside-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Comment: If I take the ViewPager out of the AppBarLayout the same problem exists

Comment: Refer this link https://gist.github.com/iPaulPro/1468510f046cb10c51ea

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it.

1. Take out the `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` from the AppBarLayout.
2. Remove `scroll` from the layout_scrollFlags of the toolbarLayout.

So instead of this: `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`,
make sure you have something like this:
`app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"`