# collapsing toolbar not working properly

Tags: android, toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

[image]Can anyone let me know what is wrong with this layout. The collapsing toolbar is not collapsing properly. Moreover i cannot able to change the background of the tablayout when it is pinned on the top. Would be thankful if anyone come up with the solution.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar_layout" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_main_rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="260dp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/main_bg"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ExpandedAppbarTextAppearence"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                    app:titleEnabled="true">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                            android:id="@+id/banner_ad_pager"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/banner_ad_title"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_above="@+id/indicator"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:maxLines="2" />

                        <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                            android:id="@+id/indicator"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            app:fillColor="@color/standard_brown" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scroll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix,Overdraw,MergeRootFrame">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/standard_brown"
                        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
                        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTextAppearance"
                        app:tabTextColor="@color/color_black" />

                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/dine_category_pager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />

                    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                        android:id="@+id/fab"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        app:backgroundTint="@color/standard_brown"
                        app:fabSize="normal" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header_layout"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_items_layout" />
```

Comment: can you provide an illustration of the problem?

Comment: you mean the exact design?

Comment: yup because it's hard to figure out what is not working .

Comment: i have added image. When i scroll the tab layout must fix below toolbar and i want to change the bg of tablayout as well. How could i do that?

Comment: you should refer to this answer :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30724033/2667946

Answer (score -1):

Lower the api level and rebuilt your project..hope its work