# How to pin RelativeLayout in CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using CollapsingToolbarLayout for my activity. Is there a way to pin RelativeLayout that contains Toolbar within instead of pinning Toolbar? I tried to do the following but the RelativeLayout does not pin on top when layout collapses.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="@color/pale_red"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="230dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/carViewPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="230dp"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/image_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activityTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:text="@string/shop_info"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_shop" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: How about removing the **RelativeLayout** and put **TextView** inside the **Toolbar**

Comment: Ok just tried, but TextView did not disappear by default. I want TextView to only appear when layout is collapsed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like its name **Collapsing**,everthing except **Toolbar** is going to be collapsed when scroll up, the only way to pin it is to use "**pin**" on **ToolBar**, and only the **ToolBar** works with "**pin**".
Hence try placing your **RelativeLayout** outside of **CollapsingToolBarLayout** ,but inside of **AppBarLayout**, maybe that's what you need.

I solved it through this question:

[How to use a TabLayout with Toolbar inside CollapsingToolbarLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680824/how-to-use-a-tablayout-with-toolbar-inside-collapsingtoolbarlayout)

just treat your layout as the **TabLayout** mentioned in this question.

Hope it helps.