# Status bar is scrolling with CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android

It is the picture of the app while scrolling. you can see status bar is scrolled up with rest of the content which should stick to top. Also when scrolling downward it should stop collapsing in specified min-width. Which is also stopped working once i introduced the ToolBar. Before that it was working as expected.

[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.wallpapermanager.ImageDetailsActivity">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/foo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/grey_dark_transparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="200dp"
        app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/wallpaper_banner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/wallpaper_placeholder"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <!-- @Banner -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/grey_dark_transparent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:statusBarScrim="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**MAinfest**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

  <activity
            android:name=".ImageDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_image_details"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.sample.wallpapermanager.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to collapsing toolbar

Comment: @AlvinVarghese sorry not working that way.

Comment: Then try adding app:statusBarScrim to CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: @AlvinVarghese not working

Comment: Could you share the updated code along with the app theme

Comment: Please add app:statusBarScrim to CollapsingToolbarLayout, not to the toolbar.

Comment: And if you need to set the primary color to toolbar when it collapsed, try changing         app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent" to         app:contentScrim="@android:color/colorPrimary"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680824/how-to-use-a-tablayout-with-toolbar-inside-collapsingtoolbarlayout

please check this ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Works for me

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/placements"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `android:minHeight="200dp"` from `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to `AppBarLayout`.